# Redirect arbitrary subdomain to page with $_get info

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have a site that is up and running and have gotten another domain and need **redirect any visit** to `exampleA.com` or any sub-domain of it, to a page where **I can check the requested** page's sub-domain to a dynamic list of sites and if its a match **send it to that sub-domain on `exampleB.com`**, and if not send it to the main site on `exampleB.com`. there will be no site at all on `exampleA.com` is is just a shorter version of the main domain. The main site is a wordpress site.

**What I have.**

I have `exampleA.com` and `exampleB.com`  with `exampleB.com` having sub-domains.

**What I need.**

redirect `*.exampleA.com` to `exampleB.com/somePage/?from=*`

After it gets to `exampleB.com/somePage/?from=*` I can check the `$_GET` info. but I'm not sure how to set the arbitrary sub-domain to the `$_GET`

Comment: Something missing? The question?

Comment: sorry, I did not want to post it yet sorry

Comment: Do you have access to exampleA.com's httpd.conf?

Comment: yes I have root on both sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need a few things:

a) exampleA.com's DNS setup must be configured to allow wildcard subdomains:

```
*.exampleA.com. 3600 IN A x.x.x.x
```

b) exampleA.com's web server configuration must allow wildcard host matching

```
<VirtualHost ...>
    ServerName exampleA.com
    ServerAlias *.exampleA.com
</VirtualHost
```

c) exampleA.com's default document would be a simple PHP script that extracts the hostname in use and issues a redirect to exampleB with the extracted host name.

```
<?php

$requested_host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$parts = explode('.', $requested_host);
array_pop($parts); // com
array_pop($parts); // exampleA

$requested_subhost = implode('.', $parts);

header("Location: http://exampleB.com/?from=$requested_subhost");
```

Comment: So if `exampleB.com` has a wildcard (and it does) the default for `sub1.exampleA.com` (and all others) will be the default for `exampleA.com`?

Comment: I guess I was asking the wrong question from the start, I did not know that a default page would be shown on sub-domains that were empty. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you match the domain name against the list (which you can get from `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`), you can then redirect the user dynamically using PHP's `header('Location: http://example.com/')`.

Comment: to do that wouldn't I need to know the sub-domain and have it setup in IIS. what I'm realy needing is `*.exampleA.com` to `exampleB.com/somePage/?from=*`

Comment: Yep, when you check `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, it gives you subdomain.exampleA.com, from which you can get the subdomain and redirect using `header('Location: ...').